# Remove duplicate from dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have 5 lists in a dictionary I want to delete duplicates and retain the element that occurs in first list by comparing all lists available

```
dict = {1:[0,1,2,3], 2:[1,4,5], 3:[0,4,2,5,6], 4:[0,2,7,8], 5:[9]}
```

Output should look like this:

```
dict = {1:[0,1,2,3], 2:[4,5], 3:[6], 4:[7,8], 5:[9]}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also not that there is no actual order to the keys/values in a dictionary.  What happens if I look at 2 before I look at 1.  Do you require the keys to be sorted numerically?

Comment: @sahasrara62
 I Tried running a loop over the dictionary, stored them in two separate variables and compared them using a set operation

Comment: @FrankYellin From python 3.7, dict does preserve order.

Comment: @j1-lee.  You are correct.  In 3.6, this was an implementation detail of CPython.  But I see that in 3.7, it's been made official.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a set to store items that have been seen, and then sequentially update the dict according to the set:

```py
d = {1:[0,1,2,3], 2:[1,4,5], 3:[0,4,2,5,6], 4:[0,2,7,8], 5:[9]}

seen = set()
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = [x for x in v if x not in seen]
    seen.update(d[k])

print(d) # {1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6], 4: [7, 8], 5: [9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner with a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [i for i in v if i not in sum(list(dct.values())[:idx], [])] for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(dct.items())}
{1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6], 4: [7, 8], 5: [9]}
>>>
```

It filter and flattens all the values in the list before the certain key and filters the values not in there.

*P.S. I renamed your `dict` to `dct` so it doesn't override the function name*

Comment: Nice, not even just quadratic but *cubic* runtime. Can you make it *quartic*? :-P